# How to correctly display spacing in a span

Tags: html

I want to show the following text in a span :

```
<span>
State                      State Code<BR><BR>
ALABAMA                         AL<BR>
ALASKA                          AK<BR>
</span>
```

So I replaced the spaces with

```
&nbsp;
```

But the text still appears like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/yh7n2/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure, space with is different for different fonts (you need to to unproporcional font or better, table for this case).

Comment: I want to align the text as showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is semantically a table, so you should use `<table>` for the markup.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>State Code</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ALABAMA</td>
            <td>AL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ALASKA</td>
            <td>AK</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[`<table>` example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7MrD/)

If you absolutely must preserve whitespace, don't change your space characters to non-breaking space characters. Instead, use preformatted text:

```
<pre>
lorem   ipsum
dolor   sit
amet
</pre>
```

[`<pre>` example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vh4p/)

If you don't want to use the `<pre>` element, you can use `white-space: pre` in CSS.

Generally speaking, preformatted text works best with a monospaced font, that way all characters & spaces fill the same amount of space, so that you can align multiple lines evenly.

Comment: +1 Yes, and at that point one can modify the formatting of the table to create the appropriate amount of space.

Comment: Didn't had time to parse out the output string into a pretty table. The <pre> tags worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to wrap the span in a `<pre>` element:

```
<pre><span>
State                      State Code<BR><BR>
ALABAMA                         AL<BR>
ALASKA                          AK<BR>
</span></pre>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sA4M7/)**

Which would generate:

```
State                      State Code


ALABAMA                         AL

ALASKA                          AK
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the long state names to be aligned left and the abbreviations aligned right? If so, perhaps you would be better with `<table>`